# Можно ли в рамках прогона одного теста PyTest получить больше одного сообщения об ошибке?

Tags: pytest

Хочется понять, может ли PyTest работать а-ля Postman, где мы в одном тесте можем провести сколько угодно проверок, и тест отработает все созданные нами проверки.
Хочется чтобы тест упал, но только после того, как будут завершены все проверки, и получить отчет о всех причинах падения теста, а не о первой, в которую тест "уперся".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39896716

Comment: Большое спасибо! Будем изучать

Comment: Там в ответах упоминается pytest-assume, но не похоже, что он сильно живой. Есть живой аналог (от автора pytest-expect, от которого был форкнут pytest-assume) - https://github.com/okken/pytest-check

Comment: А, хотя pytest-check там тоже упоминается